# Accessing DB with Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning MVC4 with Entity framework. Today I figure out how to update junction table and now I'm little bit confused about linq usage. Normally I update my db with following statement.

```
db.Entity.Add(EntityViewModel);
               db.SaveChanges();
```

However when I update junction table

```
 Entity EntityAttached = db.Entity.Where(x=> x.Id ==   EntityViewModle.Id).First();
   EntityViewModle.anotherEntities = EntityAttached.anotherEntities;
   EntityViewModle.anotherEntities.Clear(); EntityViewModle.anotherEntities.Add(anotherEntity);

db.Entry(EntityAttached).CurrentValues.SetValues(EntityViewModle);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It works fine but, I don't really get db.Entry().CurrentValues.SetValues() part. Please explain me why I just cannot use .add() and save. Or else Is there anyway to directly enter the data to the junction table? or more simpler way rather than described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this code updates the existing entity. If you would use Add then you'd get new ID from the database.